# Android sensor monitoring app with threshold control

Tags: android, monitoring, hardware, alarm-clock

I am interested in the app which allows  to monitor different built-in sensors of device (particularly ALS sensor) not only manually but also in unattended mode. And also it should include sending results to email.
What I imply under "monitoring"? It's not showing dumb graphs to user, but rather specification of threshold values (**not less than** 5 lux and/or **not more than** 20 lux) and alarming me by email or SMS in case of exceeding them. 
All the apps I've seen before allowed doing this only manually and without thresholds.

Comment: I have not used such one yet, but maybe you find it in my [list of sensor apps](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/sensors). There's e.g. [Sensorium](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=at.univie.sensorium): open source, also [available at F-Droid](https://f-droid.org/repository/browse/?fdid=at.univie.sensorium) which permits to define thresholds, monitoring defined sensors, and upload collected data.

Comment: @Izzy, but I see the Sensorium lacks ALS sesnsor, no? Maybe you could point out which of you apps support it?

Comment: As I wrote, I have not used one of such yet – and it's not "my apps" but just "my list". Sorry, but I cannot help you further on that; I've just thought the list might give you a chance to identify a candidate while waiting for good recommendations – and maybe then you could even answer your question yourself.

Comment: @Izzy, got it. I wrongly considered you developed these apps. Thank you for search direction though.

Comment: Anytime! And while I may be quite busy, developing 13k+ apps (that's what my app lists currently cover) is too much for a single person :)

Comment: @Suncatcher I don't know why are there so many people that don't know about Tasker.